# implicit declaration of function 'gdPngGetVersionString' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

Tags: php, makefile

OS: macOS 11.1

Php 8.0.0

When I compile Php 8.0.0 and met the error:

```
error: implicit declaration of function 'gdPngGetVersionString' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

And I try to set `CC=c89`, but failed

How can I resolve it.

Comment: SO is for helping you fix problems in code that you're writing. If you're getting an error when compiling someone else's code, you should report the problem to the developer.

Comment: `c89` is not the name of a compiler. If you want to specify the language version, that's done in `CFLAGS`.

Comment: But it seems extremely unlikely that the PHP code requires implicit declarations.

Comment: of course, unless you have an overriding requirement to `make` your very own php 8 on your mac, you could rely on old trusty `Homebrew` and use that as your package manager, and brew php on your box.  Not certain about BigSur (ie i banned updates to that pos) , but the Hombrew crew announced support for intel boxes on december 20.